# Cron job creating new file

Tags: linux, cron, cpanel

I'm using a cpanel where I've hosted an application. In my application I have to run some queries on minutes/hourly/daily basis. For that I'm using cron job from cpanel. Here is a cron command that I'm using:

```
* * * * * wget -O /dev/null https://******/sms_cron
```

The problem in this command is, it is sending an email when it trigger. After searching for solution in online to stop sending email, I've found this command useful:

```
* * * * * wget https://******/sms_cron > /dev/null 2>&1
```

But there is a problem with this command too. Though it has stop sending email, but it is generating new file every time it trigger. Now I have to idea how to stop that too. Can anyone help me out with that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To stop `wget` outputting *anything*, redirect its output to `/dev/null` *and* ask it to be quiet.

```
* * * * * wget -O /dev/null --quiet 'URL'
```

This is equivalent to

```
* * * * * wget -O - --quiet 'URL' >/dev/null
```

It will still produce output for actual errors (which I presume that you want to see). To avoid these as well, add `2>/dev/null` to the end of the first command, or `2>&1` to the end of the second command.

Comment: I don't want to generate any file/sending any email, hopefully your solution will work. I will let you know. Thank you for your quick response

Comment: Thanks,.. It worked